# Setting multiple margin on responsive website

Tags: css

how can I set a different margin for different resolution. For example max-width: 767 margin 0, min-width 768 margin 50 and min-width 1200 margin 150

Comment: use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: 50px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    margin: 150px;
  }
}
```